# Лишний символ перед строкой

Tags: c#

Клиент должен считать строку с помощью ReadUTF() - значит, нужно сначала записать кол-во символов в строке ushort, а затем саму строку.
Я так и делаю

```
string email = "test@yandex.ru";
ushort lemail = Convert.ToUInt16(email.Length);
...
writer.Write(lemail);
writer.Write(email);
```

Но в клиенте получаю \u000etest@yandex.r

Comment: и Вы попробовали НЕ писать длину прежде чем задать вопрос?

Comment: Если вы пишете сперва число, потом строку, то и читать (с помощью BinaryReader) нужно соответственно сперва число, потом строку: `ReadInt32`, `ReadString`. Вы же явно читаете сразу строку.

Comment: Что такое `ReadUTF`? Откуда этот класс/метод, из какой  библиотеки, из какого пространства имён?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась привидением строки в UTF-8

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(email)
```

Comment: Бред какой-то...